# linq groupby() and Sum()

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

This is probably quite trivial but I can't get it to work (linq level novice).

I want to group and sum the rows for a client that fall on the same day (The date is shown in epoc/unixtime).

At the moment its just showing the max as 21 (converted from Kbytes to Gbytes), and not ±26 which is what I want to see.

How do I add the `GroupBy` and `Sum` clauses to add the Kbytes for each day?

```
public class Images
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string ImageID { get; set; }
    public int PolicyType { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleType { get; set; }
    public Int64 BackupTime { get; set; }
    public Int64 KBytes { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public static List<Images> images = new List<Images>();
```

and

```
    public void calc()
    {

        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            totalmax = 0;
            totalavg = 0;
            foreach (var ptype in ptypes)
            {

                var windowsquery = images
                    .Where(s => s.PolicyType == Convert.ToInt16(ptype) && s.ScheduleType == 0 && s.ClientName == client)
                    .Select(s => s.KBytes);

                double typemax = windowsquery.DefaultIfEmpty().Max()/1048576;
                totalmax = Math.Round(totalmax + typemax);
                double typeavg = windowsquery.DefaultIfEmpty().Average()/1048576;
                totalavg = Math.Round(totalavg + typeavg);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Client = {0}, Max = {1}, Ave = {2}", client,totalmax, totalavg);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Ouput (omitted other clients from output)

Client = Client2, Max = 21, Ave = 14

Update: Implemented this

```
var summary = (from image in images
                           where image.ScheduleType == 0
                           group image by new
                           {
                               image.ClientName,
                               image.PolicyType,
                               image.ScheduleType,
                               BackupDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                                                                       .AddSeconds(image.BackupTime)
                                                                       .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                           } into imageGroup
                           select new
                           {
                               ClientName = imageGroup.Key.ClientName,
                               PolicyType = imageGroup.Key.PolicyType,
                               BakupDateTime = imageGroup.Key.BackupDateTime,
                               SumGBytes = imageGroup.Sum(s => s.KBytes) / 1048576.0,
                               AvgGBytes = imageGroup.Average(s => s.KBytes) / 1048576.0,

                           }
                                    ).ToList();
```

But the Sum totals are not correct, averages work fine.

[image: Console Ouput]

[image: Excel Comparison]

Comment: Does this input contains all records for Client1 and Client2? If so, then max for Client2 is ~21, not ~26. Why do you expect 26?

Comment: Yes, this sample input is correct. Because the date (1463234422 & 1463234420) is on the same day. I want the size for one day sum'd

Comment: Ok, you're right, I haven't noticed this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one:

```
var summary = (from image in images
               group image by new { image.ClientName, 
                                    image.PolicyType,
                                    BackupDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                                                .AddSeconds(image.BackupTime)
                                                .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                  } into imageGroup
               select new { ClientName = imageGroup.Key.ClientName, 
                            PolicyType = imageGroup.Key.PolicyType,
                            BakupDateTime = imageGroup.Key.BackupDateTime,
                            SumGBytes = imageGroup.Sum(s => s.KBytes) / 1048576.0,
                            AvgGBytes = imageGroup.Average(s => s.KBytes) / 1048576.0,
                            MaxGBytes = imageGroup.Max(s => s.KBytes) / 1048576.0,
                            Records = imageGroup.Count()
                          }
              ).ToList();
```

You can use the following query to list all records with converted BackupTime:

```
var listWithDateTime = (from image in images
                        orderby image.ClientName ascending, 
                                image.PolicyType ascending, 
                                image.BackupTime ascending
                        select new { 
                                 ClientName = image.ClientName,
                                 PolicyType = image.PolicyType,
                                 GBytes = image.KBytes / 1048576.0,
                                 UnixTimestamp = image.BackupTime,
                                 NormalDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                                            .AddSeconds(image.BackupTime)
                                            .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
                               }
                       ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. The sum its generating is not correct, but the average is correct. I've put the input in excel and verified it line by line.

Comment: Can you provide one example of incorrect sum, for example: [date], [client], [correct_sum], [incorrect_sum]

Comment: In the pictures I uploaded you'll see that in the console output it shows the average and it matches what is listed in the excel. In most cases there is only 1 instance per day so average = total. And for a few there are 2 instances where the average listed in console equals 50% of the total.

Comment: I've modified a little bit my linq query - added **Records** and **MaxGBytes**. Can you run this query once again and check if the returned **Records** value for each group equals to the amount from Excel?

Comment: I believe that some records are duplicated. I've added a helper query **listWithDateTime** - try this one and check if there are some duplicates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112223/discussion-between-riaan-badenhorst-and-pikos).

Comment: I had duplicates. My list.Add was being called times. The modified query highlighted this. I've cleaned it up and stuck with the first one you posted. Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

have you already tried this one?

```
 var windowsquery = images
                    .Where(s => s.PolicyType == Convert.ToInt16(ptype) 
                     && s.ScheduleType == 0 && s.ClientName == client)
                    .GroupBy(s => s.date)
                    .Select(s => s.Sum(y=>y.KBytes));
```

In the picture that you have included, the date seems not correct or is it a special format?

Comment: Hi, the date is in unix time (seconds from 1970/01/01) but I've found another method to convert that. For testing I can try to just make the "date field" from 2 rows match to see if the groupby works.

Comment: I tried this now and recall I did it earlier today. when I put the groupby in front of the select the Kbytes goes red and it says "The name Kbytes does not exist in the current context". If i remove groupby, it looks fine again.

Comment: yes sorry i wrote it on the fly, corrected now with : Select(s => s.Sum(y=>y.KBytes)); I am more used to query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It seems repeated post., Answers are already available in Stack overflow...

```
var windowsquery = images
                .Where(s => s.PolicyType == Convert.ToInt16(ptype) && s.ScheduleType == 0 && s.ClientName == client).GroupBy(s => YourDateField)
                .Select(s => s.Sum(i => i.KBytes));
```

or

```
 var windowsquery = images
                        .Where(s => s.PolicyType == Convert.ToInt16(ptype) && s.ScheduleType == 0 && s.ClientName == client).GroupBy(s => YourDateField)
                        .Select(g=>new { sum = g.Sum(k=>k.KBytes), field = g.Key });
```